# How to change logo in protected web page in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website that I think has protected pages and I can't change the logo in them. Website is built in C Sharp.

In that protected pages I only have this code below:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="login.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false"
    Inherits="ecdltest.Pages.Public.login" %>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phPage" Runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I have tried to change logo by replacing the same image with another one but it didn't help.

Please if anybody can help me with this.

Comment: Protected pages? What does that mean? Changing the picture to a new one will most certainly change it...

Comment: I can help you brother but just tell me properly what is the problem actually. @Milan

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with a logo image. If you correctly replaced the image did you do a hard refresh (CTRL + F5)

Comment: Can you send code of login.aspx

Comment: Only code that I have is that code above. I can't see nothing, but when I inspect the page using web browser I can see the code of a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit long for a comment, so posting as an answer:

A) I assume you need to replace a logo on "login.aspx", which is why you arrived at that file. If this is the full markup in that file, then that placeholder (phPage) is filled with the actual contents. That filling is done by the codebehind, which is in "login.aspx.cs". Maybe that code is reading from some other (aspx, ascx, ..) file, where you *can* replace the image.

B) The image may be defined in some master page, which will be put around this aspx code. So check if that is the case and replace the image there.

C) Finally, in the rendered page (in the browser), see where the image is coming from. Can you relate that to a location on disk? If you can, then overwrite that image file with the new logo (keeping the original name). Beware of browser caching still showing the old logo when you have correctly replaced it on the server.

Good luck.

Comment: Dear Hans, thank you for your answer. I tried to find login.aspx.cs but it doesn't exist. There are no aspx.css pages in website folder. Can you tell me what could happen with them?

Comment: Then you have only the compiled version of your site. All *.cs files have been compiled into a .dll. For any real changes, you will need the original sources.